# Trouble with click toggle animation

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle

I am having some issues with this jQuery nav I am building. When you click "Find zip", the zip code finder is supposed to fall down to 175px, then when clicked again, fly back up to 90px.

This set used work perfectly the first time, however it got stuck at 90px shortly there after. After a little playing around, it plays both animation consecutively, no break, no click. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('a#find-zip').click(function(event) {
    $("div#zip-drop").toggle().stop().animate( { top: 180 }, { duration: 'slow', easing: 'easeOutBack'})
    $("div#zip-drop").toggle().stop().animate( { top: 90 }, { duration: 'slow', easing: 'easeOutBack'}) 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var toggle = true;

  $('a#find-zip').click(function(event) {
     if (toggle === true){
        $("div#zip-drop").animate( { top: 180 }, { duration: 'slow', easing: 'easeOutBack'});
        toggle = false;
     }

     else{
         $("div#zip-drop").animate( { top: 90 }, { duration: 'slow', easing: 'easeOutBack'});
         toggle = true;
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah, I always forget to use var. Thanks so much!